# Javascript speech recognition, clear results?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

I would like to make some features available in my cms with webkitSpeechRecognition.

For example when a user says "new page", a modal pups up with a form.
And that works, but i want to push it one step further and when the modal pops up i want him to be able to say the label's name and that corresponding input field should focus.

After that of course i would allow him to say the content of the input field.

So the first two things are working, he can say "new page" and the form pups out, after that he can say one of the labels name and that input field focuses, but i keep loging his speach command and i dont like the fact that because i set:

```
 var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
     recognition.continuous = true;
     recognition.interimResults = true;
```

The text keeps incremented, for example lets say he whants a new page with the name of contact, then i would like to see the result of his speach to be:

```
"new page"
"contact"
```

And no more, but now i see:

```
new page
new page contact
contact
new page contact
```

And things like that. Is there a way to clear the results after lets say it matches on of my commands?

Comment: once you get a match, clear the previous results so you start "clean".

Comment: @MarcB that is what i would like to do, yes, but how ?